# Create GameObject as parent of another GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want from script Instantiate gameobject but gameobject which I want to Instantiate should be parent of another Gameobject. How do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
GameObject g = Instantiate(Prefab,parent.transform,false);
```

it automaticly sets the parent.transform as g's parent.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
GameObject1.transform.parent = GameObject2.transform;
```

now GameObject1 should be the parent of GameObject2.

Comment: But I use  Instantiate() function. Im need gameobject which created with  Instantiate() do as parent of another gameobject.

Comment: You could Instantiate it first and then set it as a parent, but I think you can't set prefabs as parents in Unity. Would you could do is, instead of having a prefab you could have a hiden copy of that object in your scene and then Instantiate a copy of that and set it as a parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
GameObject go1 = GameObject.Find(/*child GameObject name*/);
GameObject go2 = Instantiate(prefab);
go1.transform.parent = go2.transform;
```